# Plotly - Fill area between three lines - How do I remove this dark shadows

Tags: plotly, data-visualization

```py
fig = go.Figure(layout_yaxis_range=[0,10])

fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(
    x=df['date'],
    y=df['25 Percentile'],
    name = '25th Percentile',
    mode='text',
    line=dict(color='blue'),
    fill='tonext',
    fillcolor='grey',
    connectgaps=False
))

fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(
    x=df['date'],
    y=df['Median'],
    name = 'Median',
    mode='lines',
    line=dict(color='green'),
    fill='tonexty',
    fillcolor='#eaecee',
    connectgaps=False
))

fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(
    x=df['date'],
    y=df['75 Percentile'],
    name = '75th Percentile',
    mode='text',
    line=dict(color='blue'),
    fill='tonexty',
    fillcolor='#eaecee',
    connectgaps=False
))

fig.update_layout(template='plotly_white')
fig.show()
```

I'm trying to fill area between three lines But can't get rid of this dark shadows.
I have tried to make sure fill='' parameter is right by changing it to all available values but not sure which one will work.

How do i remove this dark shadows?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Care to share the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have simulated data to be able to re-produce
- there were two issues with you code

  - two traces were defined as `mode="text"` have changed to `mode="lines"`
  - only want `fill="tonexty"` on percentile traces

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range("30-mar-2022", "15-may-2022")}).assign(
    val=lambda d: np.random.randint(1, 10, len(d))
)

df = df.join(
    df["val"]
    .rolling(5)
    .agg(["median", lambda w: np.percentile(w, 25), lambda w: np.percentile(w, 75)])
).dropna()
df.columns = ["date", "val", "Median", "25 Percentile", "75 Percentile"]


fig = go.Figure(layout_yaxis_range=[0, 10])

fig.add_traces(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["date"],
        y=df["25 Percentile"],
        name="25th Percentile",
        mode="lines",
        line=dict(color="blue"),
        # fill='tonext',
        # fillcolor='grey',
        connectgaps=False,
    )
)

fig.add_traces(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["date"],
        y=df["Median"],
        name="Median",
        mode="lines",
        line=dict(color="green"),
        fill="tonexty",
        fillcolor="#eaecee",
        connectgaps=False,
    )
)

fig.add_traces(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["date"],
        y=df["75 Percentile"],
        name="75th Percentile",
        mode="lines",
        line=dict(color="blue"),
        fill="tonexty",
        fillcolor="#eaecee",
        connectgaps=False,
    )
)

fig.update_layout(template="plotly_white")
fig.show()
```

[image]